# Enabling BLE on iPhone. Not working by default

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am pretty new to iOS dev. I started building a BLE app a month back and it works fine in foreground and background and there is nothing wrong with BLE connection as such.
I restored my phone last week. After restarting the moment I tried running my app in my iPhone. It started crashing. The code was breaking on this line.

```
[self.manager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)peripheral.UUID]];
```

with a SIGABRT signal. I installed endomondo and tried pairing my sensor with it. It asked me to enable ble and I tapped yes on the dialog and the belt paired. After that I checked my app and it started working fine too. 
What I think is that since before making my own app, I had endomondo installed so something was enabled already for my app to work fine. I cant really understand what needs to be done to enable my app for ble operations without having any other app to do this for me. 
Help me fix this. Do we need to set something else to enable ble rather than just enabling bluetooth from settings?

Comment: What's in periphearl.UUID? Well, what's in it at the start?
retrievePeripherals is for asking the central to retrieve a list of known peripherals by their UUIDs. Your peripheral.UUID was it null?

Comment: Yes its null only when it gives the error. Can it be overcome by directly calling [manager connectPeripheral] and then when its once connected, I use retrievePeripheral everytime

Comment: You have to retrieve peripheral only if you know one...
Check CoreBluetooth Temperature Sensor, sample from Apple. You can check the method `loadDevices`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, certain versions of iOS 6.x would return screwy results around the UUID property of a peripheral. Sometimes it would come back as nil when it should have been a legitimate value. I ended up using a workaround like this for those cases in one of my applications:

```
if (aPeripheral.UUID != nil)
{
    [centralManager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)aPeripheral.UUID]];
}
else
{
    [self centralManager:centralManager didRetrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aPeripheral]];
}
```

That passed the peripheral directly into the delegate method, avoiding the retrieval step, and the application seems to work reliably when I do so. I believe this was no longer needed after I upgraded to a newer point release of iOS 6.0.

Comment: I also thought of doing that, but I wasnt sure if thats the optimum way. But Imma go with this now only. Thanks!